# I cann't call my localhost by ip address

Tags: xampp, hosts

I am trying to call my xampp localhost from another computer's browser, I have changed host file at C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc by appending (192.168.1.105 localhost) at the end this file and save it and then restart computer, but I could not call my localhost from another computer.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is this computer in local internet place?

Comment: Yes, these two computers are the same network.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access port forwarding in your router and forward port 80 only as TCP. Also, the host file code should look something like `YOUR IP     YOUR IP` and not `YOUR IP    localhost`. Furthermore, you need to edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` from apache folder in xampp instalation with something like that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin whatever@whatever.com
DocumentRoot "PATH TO YOUR FOLDER"
ServerName YOUR IP   
ServerAlias YOUR IP   
</VirtualHost>
```

After that you must restart apache in XAMPP control panel (MySQL not necessary)

THE SOLUTION ABOVE WILL LET YOU SEE YOUR CONTENT FROM ANYWHERE AS LONG AS YOUR LOCAL PC IS TURNED ON AND HAVE INTERNET CONNECTION. THE SOLUTION BELOW (I DIDN'T TEST IT, BUT I GUESS IT WILL WORK) WILL LET YOU ACCESS YOUR CONTENT FROM LOCAL NETWORK ONLY.

edit your `httpd-xampp.conf` file as following and after that you should probably need to perform a **browser cache cleaning**

```
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you please to show me how to change host file.

Comment: Under the 127.0.0.1    localhost put YOUR IP  (ONE TAB SPACE) YOUR IP in host file from etc folder. If you have an antivirus like Avira may be blocking you to edit this file. In this situation you will have to go to your antivirus settings.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `192.168.1.105 localhost` on the other PC (the one you want to use to view your website), it will look for a website on the same machine. Delete the entry from the hosts file and enter the IP address in your browser and it should work if the webserver is running.